# Is it possible to authenticate with Azure AD to access Dynamics Web API using Client Credentials Grant

Tags: authorization, microsoft-dynamics, azure-active-directory

I have an web app that has been defined on Azure AD to have permission to a Dynamics 365 (Delegated Permissions).

And I'm using [Client Credentials Grant](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/credentials.html) to get Access Token from azure AD. So I'm doing this:

```
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(dynamicsTenant, clientCredential).Result;
```

But I keep getting HTTP 401 when I try to access the Web APIs like this:

```
var response = httpClient.GetAsync(dynamicsTenant + "/api/data/v8.1/contacts").Result;
```

It works with [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html), like this:

```
var userCredential = new UserPasswordCredential("crmuser", "crmpwd");
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(dynamicsTenant, clientId, userCredential).Result;
```

Is there a possible configuration on Dynamics 365 that could be prohibiting the access?

My aim is to consume the Dynamics (Online) Web API from a (headless) confidential client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of permissions that AAD supports, which match up to the two main types of authentication methods.

There are application permissions and delegated permissions, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications).

> Application Permissions: Your client application needs to access the
> web API directly as itself (no user context). This type of permission
> requires administrator consent and is also not available for native
> client applications.
>
> Delegated Permissions: Your client application
> needs to access the web API as the signed-in user, but with access
> limited by the selected permission. This type of permission can be
> granted by a user unless the permission is configured as requiring
> administrator consent.

In order to use your delegated permissions, you can use the [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#oauth-20-authorization-flow).

If you use the Client Credential Flow to get your access token, the expectation is you must request Application Permissions; otherwise, you will get an unauthorized.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That's the answer I was kinda expecting but didn't want to hear.

Comment: Why do you say that? Delegated vs Application permissions is a very important segmentation. The permissions a client app has to an API can and should vary greatly depending on the token context. If I am creating an Email Management app, it is a reasonable expectation that my app can delete emails if I am signed in, but not when the app doesn't have my user token, and is acting in the app only mode.

Comment: I agree it is a reasonable expectation. It just means in my case, I may have to have a Dynamics login for my app, as I do not have a user token, nor a user to login so I can get a user token.

Comment: Why not use Application Permissions and then use the Client Credential Flow? Are those not exposed?

Comment: I do not see an Application Permission to be able to select/grant; instead I just Delegated Permissions. I'm using the new Azure portal and have no access to the old portal (possibly due to subscription type, I'm not sure).

Comment: Actually, now I'm using a different Azure login and could get to the old portal. But it only allows you to set Delegated Permissions for Dynamics CRM Online; there is no Application Permission/s.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should see "No application permissions available." text if there are no available app only permissions. If that is the case, then the API was not designed to support App Only Flows. If you are trying to build this for your own use, then it might make sense to create a 'service account' which is basically a fake user account which you can use to sign into the application.

Comment: That looks like the path I need to take, which makes sense because there are security roles that Dynamics enforces to allow you to perform actions within the app.